# what does "ls -t | head -n 1" in linux do?

Tags: linux, bash

Could someone explain to me what line before `fi` does?

```
if [ -f $fname ] 
then 
    echo "File already exists"; 
else 
    touch $fname; 
    echo "File has been created"; 
    ls -t | head -n 1; 
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, it prints the most recently modified in the current working directory.

From `man ls`:

```
-t     sort by modification time, newest first
```

From `man head`:

```
-n, --lines=[-]K
       print the first K lines instead of the first 10;
       with the leading '-', print all but the last K lines of each file
```

However, I'm not sure why it goes to all this effort to do what (on first glance) seems to be the equivalent of `echo $fname`.

Considering it sets up a race condition that could cause a different filename to be printed (another file could be created between the `touch` command and the `ls` command). This may or may not be deliberate.

Comment: Really great teach-a-man-to-fish answer. Interesting point about the race condition, too. What a confusing sequence of commands.

Comment: this is how the actual code is :-echo "Enter the filename="; 
   read fname; 
   if [ -f $fname ] 
   then 
   echo "File already exists"; 
   else 
   touch $fname; 
   echo "File has been created"; 
   ls -t | head -n 1; 
   fi 
   ;;

Comment: *** we have used if in above code so to close the if we use fi at the end of code***